# How to migrate react native app from API level 30 to 31

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-manifest

What are the steps to migrate a react native app from API level 30 to 31.
What should I take in consideration ?
Should i update all dependencies ?
I'm using many dependencies, and there are some native. What are the moments that i can encounter doing this ?
How hard is it ?

Comment: Review changes in 30 API to 31 API, then you can just update React Native in your project, optionally some things can crash but mostly they should not as packages have mostly locked react-native version they support. You not necessary need to update all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your project and the API level changes, migrating a React Native app from 30 to 31 may need several stages. General steps:

- **Upgrade React Native**: Check the React Native docs to make sure your version supports API level 31. Upgrade to a compatible version.
- **Upgrade Native Dependencies**: Make sure your app's native dependencies, such React Native Navigation, are updated to API level 31-compatible versions.
- In your app's build.gradle file, update the Android Gradle Plugin to 4.2.0 or higher.
- **Update Build Tools**: Upgrade your app's build.gradle build tools to 31.0.0 or higher.
- **Upgrade Android SDK**: Use the newest Android SDK that supports API level 31.
- **Deprecated APIs**: Replace any deprecated APIs in your programme with the suggested equivalents.

To confirm API level 31 compatibility, test your app.

These are generic processes, and your app and the new API level may require different actions. Hence, API level 31 release notes and documentation should be thoroughly reviewed for any further modifications or needs.